# google maps. Как определить нахождение точки в объекте map feature?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, google-maps

Общая задача - заполнить города, в пределах границ, квадратными полигонами.
Получаю границы городов:

```
this.map.data.loadGeoJson('server/cities.json');
```

Для Москвы например, это массив из >1000 элементов, перебирать его плохая идея.
Как определить принадлежит ли точка на карте этой области (городу) ?

Comment: берите  координаты(lat/lng) по клику на карте, и используйте Google Geocoding API или еще какое-нибудь.